# ASP.NET GridView Linking to another GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

Ok here is another thing is currently stumping me and I can not seem to find an answer that fits my need. On an aspx page I have a Grid View that gets it data from a SQL query and populates the Grid View, which is working fine. On this grid view though the first column (Column 0) has a line number that was returned from the query. There could one line or 10 or more lines in the grid view data that is returned.

What I am trying to do is add a hyperlink/LinkButton/Button (Not sure which) to the grid view in a column before the line number. I currently have a TemplateField with an asp link button which i can get to show up.

What I can't seem to figure out, and I have been looking for a couple of days now, is how to pull the cell with the line number to pass to my code behind (VB.NET) to have it run a secondary query that will populate another grid view with the line item details.

Here is how I currently have the gridview set up:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetailSecondLevel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="1010px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" CssClass="SecLvlDtl" OnRowCommand="gvDetailSecondLevel_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLineDetail" runat="server" CssClass="dtlButtons" CommandName="Edit" Text="Line Detail" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField  DataField="Line #" HeaderText="Line #" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Part Desc" HeaderText="Part Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PCS" HeaderText="PCS" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WT" HeaderText="WT" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SF" HeaderText="SF" />
            </Columns>
```

The rest of the grid view is formatting so I did not list it for brevity.

The current code behind (Which I am sure is wrong because it throws an error) is as follows:

```
    Protected Sub gvDetailSecondLevel_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    'Setup Variables
        Dim lineNumber As String = gvDetailSecondLevel.Rows(sender.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text

        'Make controls visibile
        btnClear.Visible = True
        SOThirdLevel.Visible = True

        'Retrieve Thrid Level SQL Data
        bindThirdLevel(lineNumber)
    End Sub
```

The error that gets thrown says "Public Member 'RowIndex' on type 'GridView' not found"

I should also mention that the second grid view is in a div tag that is on the same page. I am not trying to jump to another apsx page. (I can do that just fine)

So what I need is to figure out how to get the line number cell data passed to the code behind so that I can process it.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your row index, you need to use the GridViewCommandEventArgs object (e). Here is some code to get what you need:

```
Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
```

Also, cells(0) will give you the cell containing your linkbutton. So, the line that gets the row number will look like this:

```
Dim lineNumber As String = gvDetailSecondLevel.Rows(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)).Cells(1).Text
```

Comment: And this should be in the RowEditing sub of the code behind? Because I am getting an error that says the Public Override Overloads Readonly Property Cells as TableCellCollection has no parameters and its return type can not be indexed. This makes think that I am using the wrong sub ???

Comment: Based off the sub name (you didn't include your handles clause), I assumed it was taking place in your RowCommand event (which should trigger when the linkbutton is clicked).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally got it to work.

```
    'Get RowIndex
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

    'Reference Grid View Row
    Dim row As GridViewRow = gvDetailSecondLevel.Rows(rowIndex)

    'Get Cell value
    Dim lineNumber As String = row.Cells(1).Text
```

I was able to then pass the variable lineNumber to my sub and it works great now!
Thanks Wenadin for the pointer!